# Laravel how to retrieve name with user_id using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

I'm only able to fetch data with title and body attribute, but when i get data for the name it shows up empty when i refresh the page but shows when i submit automatically.

For some reason [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) is not retrieving the name successfully.

**Note:** I'm using [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel).

For example here:

Here is the server side:

**PostController**

```
public function getPosts() {

  $posts = Post::with('user')->get();
  $response = new Response(json_encode($posts));
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return $response;
}

public function storePost(Request $request) {
  $data = request()->validate([
    'title' => 'required|max:120',
    'body' => 'required|max:1000'
  ]);

  $data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
  $data['name'] = auth()->user()->name;

  $post = Post::create($data);

  $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');


  // return redirect('/home')->withMessage('A new post was created.');

  return $response;
}
```

**main.js**

```
$scope.myposts = {};

$scope.addPost = function() {

  $http.post('/auth/post', {
    title: $scope.post.title,
    body: $scope.post.body

  }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.myposts.push(data.data);

  });

  $scope.post.title = '';
  $scope.post.body = '';

};

$scope.deletePost = function(post) {
  var index = $scope.myposts.indexOf(post);

  if (index != -1) {
    $scope.myposts.splice(index, 1);
  }

  $http.delete('auth/post/' + post.id);
};

$scope.getPosts = function() {

  $http.get('/auth/posts').then(function(data) {
    $scope.myposts = data.data;
  }).then(function(data, status, header, config) {});
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default" ng-repeat="post in myposts">
  <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading">
    <% post.title %>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body panel">
    <figure>
      <p>
        <% post.body %>
      </p>
      by:
      <p>
        <% post.user.name %>
      </p>

    </figure>
    <span><button ng-click="deletePost(post)">x</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i first add content without refresh(asynchronously)

on page refresh

**above
(different log for different post)**

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain it furthermore

Comment: ah I see your problem it does not display on view?

Comment: sure, lets say i add a post  it shows the posts user along with its name, when i refresh the page, the user's name disappears. it only shows the title and body attribute like the image in the thread. 

the first post you see in the image is the title and body content without the user name

the second post you see in the image is the title and body, with the user name, but when i refresh the name disappears

Comment: @Beginner the name does not display on refresh, it just shows only when i just add the content(asynchronously)

Comment: You should change `$scope.myposts = {};` to `$scope.myposts = [];`. You have: `$scope.myposts.push(data.data);`. `$scope.myposts` must be an array `[]`.

Comment: try 'post.user.name' if this doesn't work show ur relationship

Comment: `$scope.myposts = {};` should be an array since your using ng-repeat `$scope.myposts = [];`

Comment: @Beginner `<p><% post.user.name %></p> $scope.myposts = [];` works but it seems like a wierd glitch. 

when i first add a post the user name doesnt automatically appear along with the title and content, on refresh it now appears along with the title and content. 

the title, content, and name should appear as soon as i submit data and stay there on refresh. 

so were almost there

Comment: @Beginner does that make sense ?

Comment: @Beginner let me update the post for better understanding

Comment: @Beginner i updated let me know what you think

Comment: what's the result of `console.log(data);` this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iiji.png?

Comment: check it out now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reload page is okay since

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->get();
```

returns

```
{
    "title": "title",
    "body": "body",
    "user":  {
        "name": "name"
    }
}
```

and in your angular you display it by

```
<% post.user.name %>
```

So the solution to display it when you added is to restructure your json object before pushing to array

```
$scope.addPost = function() {

  $http.post('/auth/post', {
    title: $scope.post.title,
    body: $scope.post.body

  }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);

    data.data['user'] = {
        name: data.data.name
    }

    $scope.myposts.push(data.data);

  });

  $scope.post.title = '';
  $scope.post.body = '';

};
```

Comment: you got more information on something like this, like a reference docs.